# Recyclerview layout which can be segmented into group and looks like app icons on a phone

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to customize a recycler view to show items in a grid fashion with headers for multiple sections?

Say I wanted:

```
Group 1:

x     x     x

x     x     x

x

Group 2:

y     y    y

y     y    y

y     y
```

Ideally I want each x (or y) to be an image with text under it much like apps on a phone.